# I can only edit the time-line

Tags: shortcut, timeline

As you can see from the image I'm stuck in the timeline, I pressed some hotkey but I don't know which one.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You probably hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (*Toggle Area Fullscreen*) by accident. Just do it again.